# How to solve this render overflow problem in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, row

I have been facing this render overflow problem even when my parent widget is Expanded in flutter.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(width: 80),
                      ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: widget.a.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Image.asset(widget.a[index]),
                                SizedBox(width: 25)
                              ],
                            );
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Wrap your Row with `SingleChildScrollView` instead of `Expanded` widget and set `scrollDirection` to `Axis.Horizontal` like code below:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child:  Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 80),
              ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: widget.a.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return  Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.asset(widget.a[index]),
                          SizedBox(width: 25)
                        ],
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Yes I check it. if I find another solution I'll tell you,

Comment: I edited my answer. I mean wrap your first Row in SingleChildScrollView